# Labview power and frequency sweep

Tags: labview

I am kind of new to Labview.

I am trying to control a Keysight N5173B RF signal generator to do an amplitude and frequency sweep.

I made some block diagrams, but I could not get a proper result. I could only do frequency sweep, but could not do amplitude and frequency sweep together.

Is there a generic way for amplitude and frequency sweeping? If so, could you please tell me?

Comment: What was the problem?  Why didn't it work?  Can you not vary amplitude and frequency at the same time, or did you have trouble getting the generator to accept a frequency and an amplitude change at the same time?

Comment: Post at least a picture of your attempted LabView diagram.

Comment: https://ibb.co/M9sqXHp
https://ibb.co/2NqfgvF
https://ibb.co/3R49Fmq
https://ibb.co/SJvBfGT

Comment: @JRE  https://ibb.co/M9sqXHp
https://ibb.co/2NqfgvF
https://ibb.co/3R49Fmq
https://ibb.co/SJvBfGT

Comment: @JRE i added pictures of my block diagram. Problem is, i try to make a for loop(for power sweep), and inside another for loop(for frequency sweep)

Comment: You do know you can make screen shots from the PC itself, right?  Your multi-megabyte photos are taking way to long to download on my phone through the slow connection here in Timbuktu.

Comment: Lunch break is over.  Gotta get back to work.

Comment: @JRE i think my main problem is because i make list sweep, when i change frequency amplitude also changes, i am trying to bypass this problem by algorithm development, but it is not very effective. And i could not figure out howto do step sweep